# Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync is not a function in Android Outlook

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office-dialog-api

I want to add handler to dialog I have opened using Office Dialog API. It works on desktop and in iOS Outlook app. However, it doesn't work in Android Outlook app.

When I try to call `Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync` on Android Outlook, the function is not defined. I have also tried calling `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("DialogAPI", "1.2")` and it turns out that the set is not supported (returns `false`).

How can I enable DialogAPI 1.2 on Android Outlook? I couldn't find any information about Android Outlook version necessary for this set.

The app version of Android Outlook app is `4.2240.4 (42240831)`.

Comment: As mentioned by Eugene currently Android Outlook supports only DialogAPI 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I enable DialogAPI 1.2 on Android Outlook?

The `DialogAPI 1.2` requirement set is not supported on mobile clients (Android Outlook). You need to wait until MS supports/implements it in the host applications.

You may try using the lower requirement set `DialogAPI 1.1` which should be working with `Mailbox requirement set 1.4` and `1.5` that are supported on Android. See [displayDialogAsync(startAddress, options, callback)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=common-js-preview#office-office-ui-displaydialogasync-member(1)) for more information.

Read more about `DialogAPI` requirement sets and supported hosts in the following  pages:

- [Dialog API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/common/dialog-api-requirement-sets?view=excel-js-preview)
- [Outlook JavaScript API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/outlook-api-requirement-sets?view=excel-js-preview&tabs=xmlmanifest)
- [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)